# Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'j' in

Tags: wordpress, amazon-polly

I use the Amazon AI plugin that runs amazon, Polly. 
All was Ok but know I'm getting an error.

I open the code in Cpanel.

$text = preg_replace('/<' . $value . '>(\s*?)(.*?)(\s*?)</' . $value . '>/', '', $text);

What should I do? with this error:

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'j' in /amazon-polly/admin/AmazonAI-Common.php on line 1313

Answer (score 0):

Can you use preg_quote instead of preg_replace?

Comment: When I tried I get: Warning: preg_quote() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given in